# Regex replace word in HTML without links and buttons

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I want my feature skip links in HTML.
This must skip `<a some arguments> word </a>` and `<button some arguments> word </button>`

Current regex:
https://regex101.com/r/7yMHwH/2/

I using preg_replace in PHP 5.6.
How to did that?

Current Expression:
`/(\s|^|>)(company)(\s|$|<)/i`
Example string:

```
 company<h2>About us</h2>
<h3>Our company</h3>company
<h3>Our company</h3>
<h3>Our company</h3>
<h3>Our company</h3>
<p>Our company</p>
<h3>Our team</h3>
<p>Our team</p>
<h3>Informations</h3>
<p>Informations</p>
<a href="#">company </a> <-- this is wrong
<a href="#"> company </a> <-- this is wrong
<a href="#"> company</a> <-- this is wrong
<a href="#">company </a> <-- this is wrong
<button>company</button> <-- this is wrong
```

Comment: God knows what you are trying to say you should add your code here formatted properly and your link to regex doesn't have any expression

Comment: Use the DOM to find all text nodes that contain your word (or your pattern) and that are not a descendant of a `a` or a `button` node. Use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for that.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam question was edited.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you show me any example code? I never used DOMXPath.